# Merge the tags [subclassing] and [derived-class] into [subclass]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The title says it all: there's really no difference (that I am aware of) between these tags. [subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subclass) is the largest of the three, so I chose it to be the baseline.

Wiki entries:

- [subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subclass): *A subclass is a class that derives or inherits from a parent (or super) class. Subclassing is used extensively in object-oriented programming (OOP).*
- [subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subclassing): *A subclass, "derived class", heir class, or child class is a modular, derivative class that inherits one or more language entities from one or more other classes.*
- [derived-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/derived-class): *In Object Oriented languages, derived class can inherit properties and/or member functions from a base class, also called super class. cf inheritance and polymorphism.*

Comment: Well, there is, sub-classing means something very different in the [winapi] tag for example.  These are useful as contextual tags, pretty useless to find an expert given that just about any programmer knows something about it.  So merging them is completely unnecessary and actively harmful in some tags.

Comment: @HansPassant then wouldn't it be wiser, in those tags where it makes a difference, to differentiate between [maintopic-subclass] and [maintopic-derived-class]? At the very least, somebody should add clearer distinctions between these tags to their wikis. Do you disagree with the triple-merge, or also with every possible combination of 2...? The reason I came up with this suggestion is that I honestly couldn't decide which tag to put on a question I was editing.